# Generate random 128 bit in c++ without boost

Tags: c++, random

I have a datatype of size 128 bit, and I like to generate a random value without using boost or any third party headers/libraries.
I wrote the below code snippet and it's working fine, but I want to know if there are any issues/pitfalls with the approach.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <array>
#include <iostream>
#include <random>
int main() {
    constexpr int size = 16;
    std::array<std::uint8_t, size> randomID;
    std::mt19937_64 gen_{std::random_device{}()};
    std::uniform_int_distribution<std::uint8_t> dis_{1};


    for (int i = 0; i < randomID.size(); i++) {
        randomID[i] = dis_(gen_);
        std::cout << unsigned(randomID[i]) << " ";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If your fine with the resulting data being a `array<uint_t, size>` then I see no problems with this. If the code you've shown here is followed in your real code by a `reinterpret_cast<MyRealDataType>(randomID)`, then you need to read the docs carefully to see if that cast is valid and defined for your data type.

Comment: If you need something like `char*` or `uint8_t*`, `std::vector` is easier to get the data by [`std::vector<T,Allocator>::data()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/data)

Comment: @LouisGo, I need to use the `std:;array` because of some internal decisions.

Comment: Are you allowed to use `<random>` which is part of the C++ standard library from C++11? I worry about the autocorrelation properties of `rand()` which might produce a demonstrable statistical bias in your output if you concatenate the results in this manner.

Comment: @Bathsheba, Yes I can use C++ standard library from C++11. Do you mean with `<random>` is good compared to `rand()`

Comment: @goodman `<random>` is much better than `rand()` and the result is consistent across platforms. And you don't need to generate 16 separate bytes like that because each iteration already return more than 8 bits, for example if it returns 31 bits then you only need 5 iterations

Comment: @goodman: Indeed. Draw two 64 bit mersenne twister numbers and concatenate them.

Comment: @phuclv, I replaced `rand()` with `<random>`.Regarding the iterations, there are some constraints, I need to use an array of bytes of size 16. I can't change the size.

Comment: @goodman, you can fill more items in one iteration. Eg: Fill 4 item with 64 bits random bits per iteration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One issue with the posted approach is that it will never generate a 0 octet.

```
std::uniform_int_distribution<std::uint8_t> dis_{1};
//                                               ^   the range will be [1, 255]
```

You could also use a distribution of `uint64_t` and spread the bits in the array

```
std::uniform_int_distribution<std::uint64_t> dis_{};

for ( size_t i{}; i < randomID.size(); i += 8 )
{
    auto r{ dis_(gen_) };
    for ( unsigned j{}; j < 8; ++j )
    {
        randomID[i + j] = (r >> (j * 8)) & 0xFF;
        std::cout << unsigned(randomID[i + j]) << " ";
    }
}
```

Consider also using a [`std::seed_seq`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/seed_seq) to initialize `std::mt19937`.

```
std::random_device rd{};
std::seed_seq ss{ rd(), rd(), rd() };
//                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ Increase the entropy.
std::mt19937_64 gen_{ ss };
```